# Strange link bug with hyperlink in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

When I clicked on link that redirects to Main Shop page of WooCommerce, there is blank page with no products. (see link `ПРОДУКТИ` in top right bar above the header)

When you click on button from Main Menu it is OK (button: `ПРОДУКТИ`).

I disable all plugins and change the theme, but with no luck!

See here my website Shop page: [https://www.mangustaceramics.com/продукти/](https://www.mangustaceramics.com/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8/)

Example of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPFoE.jpg

If you have any suggestions about the problem, I will be glad to hear them! Thank you!

Comment: You have to provide your code if you want someone to be able to help you

Comment: What code? I use clean WordPress + WooCommerce, with WooPress Theme and these plugins: http://i.imgur.com/GyvIV7l.png

Comment: then you should remove php and css tags at least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are technically different links. You can see this by copying the URL from the address bar and pasting them in a text editor.

The top right bar link gives this output:

https://www.mangustaceramics.com/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8/

Whereas the main menu one gives this:

https://www.mangustaceramics.com/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8/

You will need to ensure that your URLs are encoded correctly or specify them explicitly using the second link above (with lowercase letters).

Comment: I was just posting this.

Comment: Sorry to beat you to it @Eric - It's an interesting problem for sure and not immediately obvious

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty bizarre.  You think the letters got dropped to lowercase during sanitizing?

Comment: @Eric - I don't understand why the letters are different in each and I also don't understand why they provide different results in the page but I think that's another issue entirely. I don't think percentage encoding takes case into consideration so I would've thought both URLs would work...